# 'parentheses not balanced' regexp error continues to occur - I cannot identify the pattern of failure

Tags: mysql, regex

**Originally I thought this problem was a general failure of my understanding or could be generecized to a case that would be useful to others. I still haven't solved the problem, but upon learning more about the boundaries of the problem I see it is probably something highly specific and not of use to the community. Thank you for any and all help and time taken to help.**

---

**Summary**

When I pass the value `(Unit-101|00-102|Unit_103|Unit 104)` to my stored procedure (as a `VARCHAR`, to use as comparison in `RLIKE` in a `WHERE` clause) - it will generate the error `'parentheses not balanced'`. However, the stored procedure works perfectly when other values are passed in - three or less in the capture group (e.g. `(Unit-101|00-102|Unit_103)`), wildcard (`.*`) or wildcard-component (`Unit-1.*`) values work perfectly. Also, a very similar stored procedure works perfectly when more than three values are in the capture group... *(Please see below for more details. Thank you.)*

Edit: At least that's what I thought. I tried `(a|b|c|d)` (I've tried other values before which did not work) - and it worked. So I'm once again at a complete loss.

---

**Problem Context**

I have a stored procedure which includes some regex in a `WHERE` clause - it aggregates some totals for entries only where a `Unit` name matches the regex passed in to the procedure (`_r_unit`, an `IN` `VARCHAR(100)`).

This has worked as expected for many cases of `_r_unit` - `.*`, `Unit-B.*`, `Unit-101`, etc. - however in one case, when I used parentheses to capture Unit-101, or 00-102, or Unit_103, or Unit 104  - `(Unit-101|00-102|Unit_103|Unit 104)` - then the query fails with the error `#1139 - Got error 'parentheses not balanced' from regexp`.

---

**Steps attempted to find solution so far**

- *I first discovered this problem while passing in the regexp value from php, using `preg_quote` to escape the `-` characters in the unit names. However, a commenter helpfully pointed out that the `-` character should not need to be escaped here, and php will mean it needs to be 'double-escaped' anyway. So, I have tried some php-related things, but this does not appear to be the issue - now that I've eliminated that as the cause I'm just passing in values by hand using phpmyadmin to examine the conditions which cause an error.* For reference, the variable which was passed in as a value to the stored procedure from php was set to -

  `"(" . preg_quote("Unit-101") . "|" . preg_quote("00-102") . "|" 
  . preg_quote("Unit_103") . "|" . preg_quote("Unit 104") . ")";`

  The literal contents of the variable (examined by echoing it out) was `(Unit\-101|00\-102|Unit_103|Unit 104)`, as expected.
- I have also examined the regex in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to check it 'does what it says on the tin' - it's as expected, looking for `Unit-101`, `00-102`, `Unit_103`, or `Unit 104`.
- Variations on regex input I have tried.

  **Regex which does not generate the error**

  `CALL StoredProcedure('(Unit-101)');     // Or any other of the four units, non-escaped dash`

  `CALL StoredProcedure('(Unit\-101)');    // Or any other of the four units, escaped dash`

  `CALL StoredProcedure('(Unit-101|00-102)')`

  `CALL StoredProcedure('(Unit_103|Unit 104)')`

  `CALL StoredProcedure('(Unit-101|Unit_103|Unit 104)')`

  `CALL StoredProcedure('(00-102|Unit_103|Unit 104)')`

  `CALL StoredProcedure('(Unit-101|00-102|Unit 104)')`

  **Regex which generates the error**

  `CALL StoredProcedure('(Unit-101|00-102|Unit_103|Unit 104)')`

  `CALL StoredProcedure('(Unit 104|00-102|Unit-101|Unit_103)')`

  `CALL StoredProcedure('(Unit-101|00-102)|(Unit_103|Unit 104)')`

  I tried this with some random values too - and it seems to break with 4 values, regardless of what they are.

---

- I just tried running another stored procedure which takes in the same value (i.e. `_r_unit`) and it works correctly with 4 values. They are *very* similar queries so I'm trying to find a difference in the `WHERE` clauses where the regex is used but I can't find any ...

**Stored Procedure 1 WHERE clauses - Generates Error**

```
/* first WHERE clause, to retrieve results FROM one database */ 

WHERE
    `Date` BETWEEN _startDate AND _endDate 
     AND `Unit Type` = _unitType
     AND `Unit Serial` RLIKE _r_unit
     AND `Driver` RLIKE _r_driver 
     AND `Error` != ""
     AND `Error` RLIKE _r_errorCode 

/* second WHERE clause, to retrieve results FROM a second (relational) database */
/* (there are two WHERE clauses because the results are unioned together) */

WHERE 
    DB._Records.Date BETWEEN _startDate AND _endDate
    AND DB.UnitTypes.Module = _unitType
    AND DB.Units.Serial RLIKE _r_unit 
    AND DB.Drivers.Driver RLIKE _r_driver 
    AND DB.ErrorCodes.ErrorCode != ""
    AND DB.ErrorCodes.ErrorCode RLIKE _r_maintCode
```

**Stored Procedure 2 WHERE clauses - Does not generate error**

```
/* first WHERE clause, to retrieve results FROM one database */ 

WHERE 
    `Date` BETWEEN _startDate AND _endDate 
    AND `Unit Type` = _unitType
    AND `Unit Serial` RLIKE _r_unit
    AND `Driver` RLIKE _r_driver 

/* second WHERE clause, to retrieve results FROM a second (relational) database */
/* (there are two WHERE clauses because the results are unioned together) */

WHERE 
    DB._Records.Date BETWEEN _startDate AND _endDate
    AND DB.UnitTypes.Module = _unitType
    AND DB.Units.Serial RLIKE _r_unit 
    AND DB.Drivers.Driver RLIKE _r_driver
```

*(I am aware some fields are badly named however this is an old system and a lot of things are dependent on it so they would be difficult to change)*

---

I'm at my wit's end! Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: There are quotes around the regex in the PHP version, but not in the stored procedure. Is that a problem?

Comment: I don't think so? The stored procedure "knows" that `r_unit` is a VARCHAR, whereas in the written out query the quotes are needed to show it's a string. Sorry I realise I've phrased that very poorly - hope you know what I mean? Also the stored procedure causes no issues with the other status pages.

Comment: What happens when you call `CALL StoredProcedure('(Unit-101|00-102|Unit_103|Unit 104)');`? The dash (`-`) is a special character only when it's used inside square brackets (`[` and `]`) and it's not the first or the last character of the substring enclosed by them. It has no special meaning in the regex from your example.

Comment: It makes no difference. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: A debugging suggestion, after you updated the question with the code: what happens when you `CALL StoredProcedure('(a|b|c|d)')`? Or `CALL StoredProcedure('a|b|c|d')`? Is a problem with the magic number 4 or is it something else? Like the parenthesis or the values you put into the `regex`?

Comment: Gah, okay. I was pretty sure it was the magic number 4... I tried random values before and it had the same behavior - stopped working when it hit 4 - but I just tried `(a|b|c|d)` and `(a|b|c|d|e)` and they worked... ARGH, Thank you.

Comment: (What I tried before was a set of three that worked, and then added `|randomValue)` as a fourth. Which did not work.)

Comment: @Eilidh Do you have any update? Did you find where the problem is?

Comment: @axiac I'm afraid I couldn't find a thing - I tried the regex in other queries with similar `WHERE` clauses and it worked fine. I ended up changing the regex to use a whacky workaround and it worked, but I'm still at a loss.. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**This answer does not address the issue exposed in the question but it is too long to fit in a comment.**

A small quote from MySQL [RLIKE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

> Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent the newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in your REGEXP strings.
>
> ...
>
> To use a literal instance of a special character in a regular expression, precede it by two backslash (\) characters. The MySQL parser interprets one of the backslashes, and the regular expression library interprets the other.

This means the backslashes (`\`) are swallowed by `MySQL` and the regular expression engine does not see them. However, in the exposed `regex`, the dashes (`-`) have no special meaning and it's OK to leave them unquoted.

Unfortunately, this does not explain why your query fails with that strange error message.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you already solved your problem! In case not, here is how I fixed the problem of a query working perfectly at the MySQLprompt but giving the *'regexp brackets not balanced'* MySQL error when running it through PHP.

The simple solution is that one needs to add one extra backslash when going through PHP!

So, as an example, to match any of `{[(` MySQL will be happy with **REGEXP `[{\\[(]`** but the same query executed via php needs **REGEXP `[{\\\[(]`**

Hope this helps!